# Generically initialize instance of a class that conforms to protocol

Tags: swift

Have:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
   var value: Int { get set }
}

class Foo: MyProtocol {
   var value: Int
}

class Bar: MyProtocol {
   var value: Int
}
```

Want:

function `generate(value: _)` that infers the protocol-conforming class for instantiation:

```
let foo: Foo = generate(value: 1)
let bar: Bar = generate(value: 2)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What isn’t working? Your question isn’t clear.

Comment: @loremipsum my question is very clear: "Want: {this}". I didn't bog it down with details and I got a quick answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't compile because the `init` methods in the classes are missing

Add an `init` requirement to the protocol

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var value: Int { get set }
    init(value: Int)
}
```

and this `init` method in both classes

```
required init(value: Int) {
    self.value = value
}
```

Now you can create a generic `generate` method

```
func generate<T: MyProtocol>(value: Int) -> T {
    T(value: value)
}
```